# Is there an API for DBPedia

Tags: android, dbpedia

I want to develop an android application which enables the user to run queries against the DBPedia datasets and retrieve the results. Can anyone please suggest how I can achieve this? I want  to know how I can pass the queries from my application to DBPedia and retrieve results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding DPPedia is just a database that inviting you to run queries on it. Just fooling around gives me this "http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+distinct+%3FConcept+where+%7B%5B%5D+a+%3FConcept%7D+LIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on".

You can clearly see the query I ran in the URL (select distinct ?Concept where {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 100), along with a couple of other parameters. Simple grab that page from an Android app, and run an XML parser through it to get your data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found another link to a wikipedia API here http://code.google.com/p/jwpl/
Anyway I will try them both. Thanks.